# How to access inbox of facebook from app in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api, inbox

I want to access inbox of my facebook from iPhone application.
I have implemented Graph API.
How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Issue GET request http://graph.facebook.com/me/inbox with read_mailbox permission and access_token.